# Reading Data from StreamSocketListener - Upnp Subcribed Events

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

I have a problem reading data from my StreamSocketListener which drives me crazy... I'm receiving good and bad results, and I can't figure out why this happens. Good and bad means: complete and incomplete results:

Many thanks for any advise or direction. I'm already trying since a couple of days...

Method to create and start the StreamSocketListener:

```
    public async Task StartListening()
    {
        socketListener = new StreamSocketListener();
        socketListener.ConnectionReceived += onConnectionReceived;
        socketListener.Control.KeepAlive = false;

        await socketListener.BindEndpointAsync("localHostName", "Port");
     }
```

Triggered Event:

```
    private async void onConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder();
        using (IInputStream input = args.Socket.InputStream)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[8192];
            IBuffer buffer = data.AsBuffer();
            uint dataRead = 8192;
            while (dataRead == 8192)
            {
                await input.ReadAsync(buffer, 8192, InputStreamOptions.Partial);
                request.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, data.Length));
                dataRead = buffer.Length;
            }
        }
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("String: {0}", WebUtility.HtmlDecode(request.ToString())));
    }
```

The Method to Subcribe to the UpnP-Events. It works and I get notifications:

```
    public async Task Subscribe()
    {
        string HostName = App.SocketListener.Hostname;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HostName)) { return; }

        Timer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer(async (t) => { await UpdateSubscribe(); }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(250));

        foreach (var keyvalue in ServiceEvents)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("SUBSCRIBE"), new Uri(keyvalue.Value));
                request.Headers.Add("CALLBACK", "<" + HostName + ">");
                request.Headers.Add("NT", "upnp:event");
                request.Headers.Add("TIMEOUT", "Second-300");

                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendRequestAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

                SubscriberDictionary[(keyvalue.Value, keyvalue.Key, this)] = response.Headers["SID"];
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw exception;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I don't always get good results:

Good result with the last line (xml.Parsed Data):

```
String: NOTIFY / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.20:22111
NT: upnp:event
NTS: upnp:propchange
SID: uuid:57297a21-685b-464c-8c62-d312647472a4
SEQ: 0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Connection: close
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 562

<?xml version="1.0"?><e:propertyset xmlns:e="urn:schemas-upnp-org:event-1-0"><e:property><LastChange><Event xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/RCS/"><InstanceID val="0"><RoomVolumes val="uuid:29e07ad9-224f-4160-a2bc-61d17845182a=100"/><Volume channel="Master" val="100"/><Mute channel="Master" val="0"/><RoomMutes val="uuid:29e07ad9-224f-4160-a2bc-61d17845182a=0"/></InstanceID></Event></LastChange></e:property></e:propertyset>
```

Bad result without the last line (xml-Data): The Data is missing, and I don't know why?!

```
String: NOTIFY / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.20:22111
NT: upnp:event
NTS: upnp:propchange
SID: uuid:bb3bb2f9-e143-415c-b419-66a72f04d2ff
SEQ: 0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Connection: close
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 215
```

I also tried this. But again it's not working good at all. Results are comin, or I'm waiting 30 seconds+ to get some result:

```
private async void onConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    using (Stream inStream = args.Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inStream))
        {
            result = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }
```

I really need your help.

I finally came up with this solution. I seems to works quite nicely. But sometimes it takes long to get all the data. Even if the data is not huge: ?!

```
    private async Task readingDataFromConnection(StreamSocket socket)
    {
        Dictionary < string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        using (Stream inStream = socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead())
        {
            string line;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inStream))
            {
                do
                {
                    line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                    string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { ": " };
                    string[] linesplit;

                    linesplit = line.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    if ((linesplit?.Count() ?? 0) == 2) { result[linesplit[0]] = linesplit[1]; }

                } while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line));

                if (result.TryGetValue("Content-Length", out string value))
                {
                    if (Int32.TryParse(value, out int length))
                    {
                        char[] buffer = new char[length];
                        int count = length;

                        count = await reader.ReadBlockAsync(buffer, 0, length);

                        while (count != length)
                        {
                            count += await reader.ReadBlockAsync(buffer, count, length-count);
                        }
                        string data = new string(buffer);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Maybe this help anyone else...

Comment: "You must write code to handle exceptions when you call asynchronous methods on the StreamSocketListener class. Exceptions can result from parameter validation errors, name resolutions failures, and network errors. Exceptions from network errors (loss of connectivity, connection failures, and server failures, for example) can happen at any time." Please refer the remark of the [StreamSocketListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener#remarks).

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I'll change the code

Comment: @JaydenGu-MSFT: Maybe you can help me further. I successfully subscribes to Upnp-Events and I receive messages, but I receive them very slowly... It's not the network. If I check with other tools (e.g. Intel Upnp Developer Tools) the responses are comming quite quick. It drives me crazy... thanks a lot for further assistance...